# Jenkins job reserve node for itself

Tags: jenkins, distributed

I'm using jenkins with multiple slave nodes. I have two benchmarking jobs. When one of those benchmarking jobs is running I want the benchmarking job to be the only job running on that node at that time. But when the benchmarking jobs are not running, I can run multiple other jobs at the same time on a single node.

I've looked into using Throttle Concurrent Jobs but the categories don't seem to be enough to accomplish my goal. I am currently using the [Jenkins Heavy Jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin) plugin and manually setting the job weight to the number of executors that the slaves have but that is sub optimal. If the Heavy Job plugin supported a setting that would just use all the available executors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Locks and Latches Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin). One potentially serious drawback: you need to define a lock for every job that can run in parallel. So if the number of those jobs is large, etc.